# In dolphindb， I have two independent clusters. How to transfer distributed databases between these two clusters

Tags: dolphindb

In dolphindb， I have two independent clusters, which are installed on a different physical server. I want to transfer the historical data from one cluster to another. and is there any convenient way to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is backup and restore. You can backup a database in cluster A to a shared media and then restore it in cluster B